# Easy way to get function prototypes?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

A friend and I were discussing imaginary and real languages and a question that came up was if one of us wanted to generate headers for another language (perhaps D [which already has a tool](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/htod.html)) what would be an easy and very good way to do this?

One of us said to scan C files and headers and ignore function bodies and only count the braces within to figure out when a function is finished. The counter to that was typedefs, defines (which braces but defines were considered as a trivial problem) and templates + specialization.

Another solution was to read binaries produce, not the actual exe but the object files the linker uses. The counter to that was the format and complexity. None of us knew anything of any object format so we couldnt estimate (we were thinking of gcc and VS c++).

What do you guys think? Which is easier? This should be backed up with reasonable logic and fact.

If someone can link to a helpful project, one that parses C files/headers and outputs it or one that reads in elf data and displays info in an example project would be useful. I tried googling but I didnt know what it would be called. I found libelf but at this moment I couldn't get it to compile. I might be able to soon.

Comment: @George Edison: I feel like poking to tell you i'm having some fun with the compiler-design tag ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) libraries to parse C/C++ source code and extract any information you want in particular function prototypes.

Due to [library-based architecture](http://clang.llvm.org/features.html#libraryarch) it is easy to reuse parts of clang that you need. In your case these are frontend libraries (liblex, libparse, libsema). I think this is a more feasible approach then using hand-written scanner considering the difficulties that you mentioned (typedefs, defines, etc).

`clang` can also be used as a tool to parse the source code and output AST in XML form, for example if you have the file `test.cpp`:

```
void foo() {}

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

and invoke `clang++ -Xclang -ast-print-xml -fsyntax-only test.cpp` you'll get the file `test.xml` similar to the following (here irrelevant parts skipped for brevity):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CLANG_XML>
  <TranslationUnit>
    <Function id="_1D" file="f2" line="1" col="6" context="_2"
              name="foo" type="_12" function_type="_1E" num_args="0">
    </Function>
    <Function id="_1F" file="f2" line="3" col="5" context="_2"
              name="main" type="_21" function_type="_22" num_args="0">
    </Function>
  </TranslationUnit>
  <ReferenceSection>
    <Types>
      <FunctionType result_type="_12" id="_1E"/>
      <FundamentalType kind="int" id="_21"/>
      <FundamentalType kind="void" id="_12"/>
      <FunctionType result_type="_21" id="_22"/>
      <PointerType type="_12" id="_10"/>
    </Types>
    <Files>
      <File id="f2" name="test.cpp"/>
    </Files>
  </ReferenceSection>
</CLANG_XML>
```

I don't think that extracting this information from binaries is possible at least for symbols with C linkage, because they don't have name mangling.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is very helpful! I spent the last 30mins looking into things and this blows them all out of the water. I didnt mean to get the info from an elf but from a object file which i just mention elf because it looked like it could have this info in the symbol table but i didnt know much about it (one def said name and made no mention if it was managed or not).

Comment: Do you know if there is a C++ or .NET way to load this data? i think i may build up a class using C# and load the data in via with XML serialization and do my dirty work in there.

Comment: @acidzombie24: You are welcome. If writing in C++ I would use clang libraries directly because clang is in C++ and API is clean and relatively easy to use. If you plan to use C# loading XML is definitely easier.

Comment: @vitaut: I am a bit nervous about the learning curve for the API. With XML at least i can see the output and it is in an understandable format

Comment: @vitaut: how did you find these flags? for the life of me i cant find them anywhere (man pages, website, google, etc)

Comment: A document of the possible XML AST produce would be helpful as well. Its way more complex then your output.

Comment: @acidzombie24: About `-Xclang` option I have found out from `clang++ --help`. About the rest - using `clang++ -Xclang --help test.cpp` (note that `test.cpp` should exist) but I am sure there is an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

ctags' output is quite easy to read/parse

Answer (score 2):

if you want to simply generate a binding, try swig

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is [compiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler): The act of transforming code in one formal language to another. There's a good solid science behind this that, if followed carefully, will guarantee your program halts with a correct analogous code.

Granted, you don't want to parse the whole of the C++ language (hooray for that!), so you just need to define the relevant grammar and define everything else as acceptable noise or comments.

Don't use regular expressions. These won't do because C++ is not a regular language.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to define your interfaces in an abstract language (an [IDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language)), and generate headers for all languages that you're interested in. You can limit the scope of your IDL to those features that are possible in each target language.

Windows takes this approach in its [MIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367091%28VS.85%29.aspx) language, for example.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do i use IDL to generate C headers? Although useful i want it the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) can help with this. It's an advanced topic, and somewhat documented.

Answer (score 0):

#### In a perfect world...

Each compiler of any programming language would emit such information as part of its output. It could be an ELF extension or a new generally accepted file format, which contains an ELF/COFF/whatever section.

This would spare the (across the globe) thousands of man hours to generate "language bindings" for dozens of languages. Dynamic languages, such as Common Lisp would not need FFI libraries - as it all would happen under the hood and loading a shared library in that new format could automatically be inspected and functions in it could be made available on the fly, without any further ado.

And all, which actually would have to be stored as extra information for each (exported) function is:

- Generic name
- Return type
- Argument list
- calling convention (there are not that many in practice)
- A reference to the symbol table entry, referred to.

#### Why has it not been done during the past 30 years?

Because language designers still see the compiler output as their "private affair", whereas IMHO, this should be part of the OS/Runtime/Loader.

Many workarounds exist, some listed here in other answers (IDL, binding generators, such as SWIG and a myriad of others, mostly ad hoc and of varying and typically insufficient quality).

The ELF guys are Unix guys and as such C guys, who still live in a bubble, thinking C is some sort of "golden standard". But even they would not have any problems, using the information to generate their beloved header files.

RUST might not have invented crates in that perfect world and you would not even care if some shared library had been written in C or C++ or Rust or Zig or Haskell - anyone could just use it.

This domain is still dominated by "computer scientists", not engineers; while in theory, there could be an infinite number of calling conventions, in fact, those in active use are very countable few (LLVM supports many of those actually relevant).

Another reason, it has not been done yet, is that there is a danger, some committee would create a monster, trying make it "open, flexible, ..." and no one would eventually dare using it. DCE (distributed computing environment) gives that idea.